# Compiz keybindings change on reboot

Tags: 13.04, compiz, shortcut-keys

I have a problem with Compiz keybindings on Ubuntu 13.04 (but it also existed on 12.10). I run a multimonitor setup and use the Put plugin to move windows from monitor to monitor with the "Put to next output"-function.

I have bound Ctrl+Alt+Keypad Comma to move the windows. When it works, the settings window looks like this: [image: Working Compiz Settings]

However, after rebooting, the  key is changed to : [image: Working Compiz Settings](![Working Compiz Settings])

The effect is that windows move *as soon as* I press Ctrl+Alt, but before I press Comma. Since I have many other keybindings relying on Ctrl+Alt, I very often accidentally move the window because I wanted to press another shortcut. I can fix the behavior manually by entering CCSM, removing and recreating the keyboard shortcut. I should mention that this problem does not occur for any other Ctrl+Alt based shortcuts (for example in the Grid plugin).

How do I keep the shortcut persistent across reboots?

Comment: A bug? I'm running 12.04.2 LTS. Choose Primary-Alt-KPx. Save and leave the screen of the Compiz Put Plugin. When I reopen the screen the key value has changed in Control-Primary-Alt-KPx. (I don't have a second monitor. I even don't hit the key combination after I'd chosen it.)